# How to prevent a float from being placed separately on a page?

Tags: floats, page-breaking

How can one prevent a float from being placed separately on an otherwise empty page?

Comment: if you use an optional argument that does not include `p` it will not be placed on a float page unless forced out by `\clearpage`

Comment: There are a number of things that could cause it to not print before the next \clearpage, however.